# How do I set up a 5 X 5 two-dimensional array that allows for the input of all numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to programming and am struggling with the idea of setting up a two dimensional array that is 5x5 and allows for the input of the numbers 0-10. I've scratched down a few things but need some advice or guidance. The book and youtube videos can't help me any further.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numbers[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
cout << "Please enter the five scores for Contestant #1: " << i << endl;
cin  >> numbers[i]
}




int *array;
cout << "Please enter the contestants 5 scores: ";
int n;
cin >> n;
array = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: What book have you given up on? Simply impossible any books fail in explaining this.

Comment: A first book of c++. I learn best by the example programs but cant seem to find any that include both arrays and the ability to input numbers into them

Comment: ok fair enough. what about something like this: http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/array2.html

Answer (score 1):

try this:

## include

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[5][5];

//Input Data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cout << "Please enter Contestant # " << i <<"score for Test # "<<j<<" :"<<endl;
            cin>>numbers[i][j];
        }
    }
//Print Data
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cout << "Contestant # " << i <<"score for Test # "<<j<<" :"<< numbers[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```